# How to set filtering in vue template with models listing?

Tags: inertiajs

With  laravel 9/Inertiajs3 I have crud defined with route

```
Route::resource('models', ModelController::class)->except(['show']);
```

and main crud methods in control. I wonder in which way can I to set filtering by some field, like having condition
in control :

```
public function index($filter_name = '')
{
    $models= Model
        ::getByName($filter_name)
        ->paginate(5);
    return Inertia::render('Admins/Models/Index', [
        'models'       => $models,
    ]);
}
```

I suppose I need to add in routes like :

```
Route::post('models-filter', 'API\Admin\ModelController@index');
```

But how can I send POST request from vue template with models listing, which has no form defined ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use axios to make post requests!

Comment: Do you mean that having index.vue container page and to run axios to read data  and refresh content of index.vue container
without page reloading ? Please, provide a link to such decision...

Comment: if you need to take data from a different url than your current page I would use axios, instead if you need jus to take the same data but filtered and taken from the same route controller method inertia has partial reloads that allow you to refresh only the data you need: https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads#top

Comment: Do you mean that having index.vue container page and to run axios to read data  and refresh content of index.vue container
without page reloading ? Please, provide a link to such decision... Are thee some libs (like table grid) 
compatible with laravel 9/Inertiajs3